# how do I import a library in Ionic 1?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm learning Ionic to build an app that requires some linear algebra. It seems that I have to somehow import mathjs into my project.

So far, I've done this in my project's folder:

```
npm install mathjs --save
```

But now what? Where do I actually import it? I've tried writing

```
import math from 'math'
```

in `app.js`, inside `angular.module() { ... }`. When I do this, I get:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

I've also tried adding

```
<script src="js/math.js"></script>
```

in `index.html`, but that doesn't work either. I've spent all afternoon trying to find documentation or examples, but to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ionic v1, You just need to include the mathjs library in index.html page, **and mathjs exposes the global `math` object** , so you don't need to inject anything, you can call it whenever you want in your app.

**if you use bower**, just install the lib by,

```
bower install mathjs --save
```

then

```
<script src="path/to/bower_components/mathjs/dist/math.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**or you can use a cdn**

add this in index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.9.1/math.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried the second option, and it worked right away. Is there a disadvantage to doing it this way instead of using bower?